# Can I connect an iPhone to a windows 10 machine to see my work in Flutter?

Tags: windows, flutter

I want to see my work without using a simulator from Android Studio. Currently I have an Android Phone and it works when I connect my phone with Windows 10.

Can I do the same with an iPhone?

Comment: You will need a mac or hackintosh

Answer (score 0):

Flutter relies on Xcode and the iOS SDK to perform the underlying compilation and publishing of iOS apps. Unfortunately, it's not possible to do iOS development on Windows, a Mac is required.

Some googling reveals there are several online services, such as [MacInCloud](https://www.macincloud.com) and [MacStadium](https://www.macstadium.com) that provide a means to pay for a remotely accessible VM in the cloud if you'd prefer not to purchase a Mac, though not having used any, I can't personally vouch for any of them.